# Extend Facebook scope on Backand

Tags: facebook, scope, backand

I want to retrieve and save more information about the Facebook user, like facebook id, username and other information.

Is there a way to extend the Backand.socialSignup()?

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

First one is to change default behavior of server side code in social login.

To do that you have to go to "Security & auth" > "Security Actions" in your Backand application page.

Their you have an action called "beforeSocialSignup", you can edit it to save additional data that arrive from social service.
In this solution, you can't change the "scope" of request but you can add data that Backand take from Facebook like FacebookId and username.

[image: test]

Second solution, if you need more data, you can implement InApp login, and retrieve all data you need from Facebook.
In InApp login you get a token from Facebook and send it to Backand.

You have a full example [here](https://github.com/backand/IonicInAppLogin)

Comment: I implemented InApp login on facebook, did extract data what I need to store in user model. Now I want process Backand.socialSignUp and store this data. Can I pass them in socialSignUp method, or it should be separate user update  request after successful singup?

Comment: I found arg parameters in Backand.singup, but look like it dose not works for Backand.socialSignUp. Could you please, correct me? 
@Ygalbel